# Global variable for server name in all http requests?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently building out an app, using angular on the front end and laravel/php on the backend.

Within my services, I'm doing http requests to the laravel server (local testing, on a different port from Angular).  I'm concerned that once I go live, I'll have quite a few http requests I'll need to modify.

For example:

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/transaction/' + id + '?token=' + token)  
  .map(
    res => res.json()
  )
```

From the above, I'm hoping I can replace the "localhost:8000" with a globally defined variable.  Is this possible in angular?  Possibly using an http interceptor?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: add it to the `headers` of each request

Comment: Otherwise you can use an environment or static variable to store the server url

Comment: save your URL variable to src/environment.ts. And add the environment path to angular-cli.json

Comment: If you plan to serve the html and JS from your PHP backend once in production, configure the CLI server to act as a proxy, and you'll have the same setup in dev and in prod. And you won't need any server URL. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

Comment: Thanks everyone.  @Kay - adding it to the environment.ts file seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  I ended up doing the following:

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/'
};
```

and in my services files:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
...
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 'transaction/' + id + '?token=' + token)
      .map(
        res => res.json()
      )
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is good if you have flexibility to include environment files in your build routine, which not all have unfortunately.  But does have the drawback that you can't update values in it without rebuilding and deploying.

Comment: You can have multiple environment files too, if required.Just make sure to update them within angular-cli.json